# Cannot login to SQL Server using ngrok

Tags: sql-server, ngrok

Today I tried to login to a local SQL Server using ngrok with some tools (even Microsoft ones) but if I use the TCP link that ngrok gave me, it says that is impossible to login (code 18456). I searched in the MS forum but with the generic code "1" I cannot know what's wrong in the connection. If I try to login as usual with identical credentials, it works perfectly (with "as usual" I'm talking about logging with the server name like MACHINE\SERVERNAME).

**NGROK CONFIGURATION**

command to start ngrok:

```
ngrok tcp 1433
```

**ERROR CODES**

Error code 18456, state code 1

I tried I think every single one of the posts on Stack Overflow but no one worked. If it can be helpful I'm running Win11 latest (21H2).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get more information from the SQL Server error log, which has the full error code. Is this a SQL Authentication login or a Windows Authentication login? What connection settings did you use?

Comment: Is a SQL Auth login (checked the settings under database/security). For connection settings I'm using the default ones

Comment: Login failure messages are intentionally vague for security reasons. Check the SQL Server's error logs and find the 18456 errors. Take note of the `State` number mentioned in them and compare it against the `State` numbers listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the actual problem.

Comment: Post your ngrok tunnel config in your question.  And what port your SQL instance is running on ( also visible in the SQL Server logs).

Comment: don't know why, but when i check the logs they don't show the login error (i've checked that by using SQL Server Agent on Management Studio under "Error Logs" and opened every single archive and current log too) @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: Is MACHINE\SERVERNAME listening on port 1433?

Comment: yeah, if I check on SQL Server Config Manager, under config SQL native client and protocols, the default port is 1433 https://i.imgur.com/7NoYzNS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know why, but after investigating some logs I founded out that "something" else was trying to do something with the port 1433, so I tried to login after a clean boot and it works perfectly. Now I created a brand new VM with win10 and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).